# Pagination without a table

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, pagination

is it possible to work in pagination if there are no tables or do I have to change my output style entirely.

```
  <div class="row">


              <?php if ($company != null): ?>

                <?php foreach ($company as $row): ?> 

                  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="job-grid">
                    <div class="job-title-sec">
                      <div class="thumb"><a href="#"><?php echo $row['logo']; ?></a></div>
                      <div class="c-logo"> <img src="http://placehold.it/235x115" alt="" /> </div>
                      <div><h3><strong><?php echo $row['employerName']; ?></strong></h3></div>
                      <div><h3><strong>SECTOR: </strong><?php echo $row['sectorName']; ?></h3></div>  
                      <div class="job-lctn"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><?php echo $row['stateName']; ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class=""><a href="<?php echo $row['website']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>Website</a></div>
                    <div><a href="<?php echo $row['website']; ?>" class="text"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i>About</a></div>
                  </div><!-- JOB Grid -->
                </div>
              <?php endforeach; ?>

              </ul>
            <?php else: ?>
               <?php if($this->session->flashdata('none') != null) {
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
                            echo $this->session->flashdata('none');
                            echo '</div>';
                            } ?>

<?php endif; ?>
            </div>
```

There are a large number of results for the foreach and I want to split it using pagination. Thanks

Comment: besides you are having a closing </ul> without an opening <ul> the question is unclear. Please check https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html. It explains how open the CI pagination class actually is...

Comment: Yes you can use pagination without a table. Pagination is just a way of limiting results per page. The actual content doesn't matter - whether a table or an ordered list.